# Eclipse not reading include file, causing segfault

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

My C source:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "xstring.h"
#include "queue.h"

struct queue* new_queue(size_t capacity, size_t data_size) {
    struct queue* queue = xmalloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->data = xmalloc((capacity == 0 ? 1 : capacity) * data_size);
    queue->rc = capacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    queue->dsize = data_size;
```

And so on, my queue.h header file defines the queue struct & some functions.

Compiling and Linking is working fine, and works if run from the command line. However, running in Eclipse debug mode causes malloc to return a pointer to a invalid address, segfaulting at the `queue->capacity = capacity;` line. I've tried moving the header around in the list, no change. I manually pasted the header contents at the top of the source file, Eclipse stopped showing errors, but still segfaulted. I tried restarting as well, no change.

xmalloc just in case:

```
void* xmalloc(size_t size) {
    if (size > 10485760) {
        printf("Big malloc %u!\n", size);
    }
    void* m = malloc(size);
    if (m == NULL) {
        printf("Out of Memory! @ malloc size %u\n", size);
        exit(1);
    }
    return m;
}
```

Below is the full queue.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_

#include <pthread.h>

struct queue {
        size_t size;
        size_t capacity;
        size_t start;
        size_t end;
        size_t dsize;
        size_t rc;
        void* data;
        pthread_mutex_t data_mutex;
        pthread_mutex_t in_mutex;
        pthread_cond_t in_cond;
        pthread_mutex_t out_mutex;
        pthread_cond_t out_cond;
};

struct queue* new_queue(size_t capacity, size_t data_size);

int del_queue(struct queue* queue);

int add_queue(struct queue* queue, void* data);

int pop_queue(struct queue* queue, void* data);

int peek_queue(struct queue* queue, void* data);

#endif /* QUEUE_H_ */
```

Comment: And how would that be related to eclipse or Linux? Suppose changing title and tags.

Comment: Does your compiler give you any warnings? Does including `stdlib.h` help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And use a debugger to track the exact location.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is anything to do with the header file?

Comment: @immibis It says it cannot resolve the struct queue type.